# Is it possible to launch the Google Drive image viewer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Basically, I want to exactly reproduce the behaviour of when you double-click on an image in a Google Drive folder and you are presented with a image viewer with all the images and videos contained in that folder. Possible? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to present the image and click in a spreadsheet or Doc?

Comment: Neither. Does it really matter? Given the URL of or programmatically retrieving a handle to the folder of interest from the Drive service, simply launch the image viewer for all pics and vids in said folder. Ultimately, I want to make a Google sites widget that is better than the currently offered and sucky old picassa widget.

Comment: @pinoyyid Care to share how?

Comment: On SO, you should only ask one question per post. It's fundamental to what makes SO a useful reference source. So please start new SO posts for your specific questions as they arise during your project.

Comment: @pinoyyid I can't decide if you're trolling me or if you're actually being serious. I know how SO works. It's an invaluable resource. I use it all the time. And sometimes there is a little discussion to clarify the question and/or answers. Sure, technically I left out what I would consider the obviously implied and more important question of "if the thing I asked about is possible, how then do I do it?"

Comment: @pinoyyid Fair enough. So, I edited the original question to explicitly ask that as well, only to get another nit-picky/smart-ass comment from you. I'm sorry, but it is you who are not being helpful and are guilty of undermining the very integrity of SO that you are claiming to champion. Please answer the "updated" question or go away.

Comment: I do think its a useful question. But list what you tried so far and didnt work so 1) you show effort and 2) those giving it a shot can discuss why it doesnt work or will try something else

Comment: Why is everyone making this process so difficult? Why does there need to be a show of effort? Like a failed code example? I'm not writing a lick of code until I know it can be done. This is called working smarter, not harder. I'm not re-inventing the wheel. Insert other metaphors for doing work that didn't need to be done. For context, I'm constructing a silly little website for just me and my friends in my spare time (of which I have very little these days as I have a young family) using Google's pretty extensive and awesome tools.

Comment: I'm essentially done and I could actually live with redirecting to Google Drive for uploading and viewing, but my research has lead me to believe that I can do this without redirecting. Awesome, right? Definitely awesome sauce! Now, how do I do that? Google Apps Script of course! I found the Google Picker for uploading files. Nice! But I couldn't find the equivalent widget for, lets call it, the Google Viewer.

Comment: So, to the crux of the situation. I have a specific question and its answer is either "No, sorry, Google has not made that widget public" or "Yes, its called <name-of-widget>, here <link> is its documentation, and guess what, just like picker it can be used with the HTML service". And all was right with the world. Please answer the question.

Comment: Bottom line, if I can't use the Google Viewer widget wholesale, then I'm not trying anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as [Google Drive Viewer](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2014/10/open-gmail-images-in-google-drive-viewer.html). Very close guess though. As far as I know, it isn't a service that you can use. However, here is Facebook's [explanation](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/developing-facebooks-new-photo-viewer/499447633919) how they implemented theirs. Hope this gives you some idea that helps you decide whether you wanna implement it or not.

Comment: Thank you. Not the answer I was hoping for, but this does seem to be the case. I guess I'll just cross my fingers that Google makes the Drive Viewer public in the near future. It would be an awesome widget to use. And I don't see why not. It seems to be at the same level of insane usefulness as Picker is. In the meantime I'll just live with redirecting to shared Drive folders.